# extjs combobox underlying textbox width is 0

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a combobox which is shown and hidden in particular scenario. The combo box renders and works fine if I don't hide it.

But once I hide it and show it again, the width of combo box is not set properly and it renders like this:

[image]

It should have been rendered as:

[image]

The HTML code of the element where combobox is rendered is:

```
    <tr valign="top" id="branchNameTr">
        <td class="td-label" id="branchNameTd">*Branch Name:</td>

        <td nowrap="" cellpadding="0" class="td-input" style="padding-left:10px;float:left">
            <span id="branchName" style="float: left"></span>
            <img border="0" alt="Branch Name " id="branchTooltip" style="float:left;padding-left:5px" src="images/info2.jpg">


        </td>
    </tr>
```

The JS code to create combobox I am using is:

```
    createRelease.branchNameList = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
        name : 'branchName',
        fieldLabel : 'Branch Name',
        store : createRelease.branchNameListStore,
        typeAhead : true,
        mode : 'local',
        forceSelection : true,
        displayField : 'branchName',
        valueField : 'branchNameId',
        triggerAction : 'all',
        emptyText : "select branch",
        selectOnFocus : true,
        minListWidth : "178",
        renderTo : 'branchName'
    });
```

On conditional basis, I am hiding the branchNameTr row as well calling hide method on the combobox like this:

```
if (packageGroupName == 'MCP') {
    document.getElementById("branchNameTr").className = "";
    createRelease.branchNameList.show();
    createRelease.branchNameList.doLayout();
} else {
    document.getElementById("branchNameTr").className = "hidden";
    createRelease.branchNameList.hide();
}
```

As you can see, I am calling show and doLayout method in "if" block which only results in the first screenshot shown above. What can I try to fix the width.

Comment: Have you tried hiding the `<span>` tag instead of the combo box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you explicitly hide the combo? Hiding the containing element is enough.

In my experience, the best way to hide some element completely is the [`setDisplayed`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Element-method-setDisplayed) method, so you should try this:

```
if (packageGroupName == 'MCP') {
    Ext.get("branchNameTr").setDisplayed(true);
} else {
    Ext.get("branchNameTr").setDisplayed(false);
}
```

Comment: did what you suggested but still same result. The inner HTML of the combo box as shown by firebug is (pls. not the width attribute):                                 <div class="x-form-field-wrap x-form-field-trigger-wrap " id="ext-gen71" style="width: 17px;"><input type="text" size="24" autocomplete="off" id="ext-comp-1034" name="branchName" class=" x-form-text x-form-field  x-form-empty-field" style="width: 0px;"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-form-trigger x-form-arrow-trigger " id="ext-gen72" style=""></div>

Comment: Are you sure you're not calling anything else? I'm assuming from your code that you're using Ext3, and I could not reproduce your problem with my code: http://jsfiddle.net/rixo/p5LFm/. (Not any more with Ext4: http://jsfiddle.net/rixo/p5LFm/1/)